# How to calling datatable from another form in c#

Tags: c#

I need calling datatable from another form, Another form is form search data for query data from database.

Form 1

```
public Showdata()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   ListBin LB = new ListBin(dt);
   LB.ShowDialog();
}
```

Form 2

```
public ListBin(DataTable dt)
{
   itemBin[] = = dt.Rows[0][0].ToString();
   listBox.Items.AddRange(itemBin);          
}
```

Comment: Add some code example to give insight in your problem and/or to reproduce your problem

Answer (score 1):

Set the access modifier of the DataTable instance in the form which contains it to `public` or `internal` using the Visual Studio Form Designer (in the properties editor you have `Modifiers`) or by changing the code itself, and you can access it from the other form.

If you have a DataTable in the Form1:

```
internal DataTable TheDataTable1;
```

If you have a DataSet containing some data tables:

```
internal Data.DataSet TheDataSet;
```

And you can write in the Form2:

```
TheForm1Instance.TheDataTable1
```

Or

```
TheForm1Instance.TheDataSet.TheDataTable1
```

You must have in the code of the Form2 class access to the Form1 instance...

Personally, I usually create all my project like this while putting the DataSet instance for the entire application in the MainForm:

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{

  static public readonly MainForm Instance;

  static MainForm()
  {
    Instance = new MainForm();
  }
```

So you can write that:

```
MainForm.Instance.TheDataTable1;
```

Or

```
MainForm.Instance.TheDataSet.TheDataTable1;
```

You can do things as you want and need.

Comment: Did I misunderstand your question or do you want a more complicated solution?

Comment: No, I just wanted to give you kudoos for trying to answer a question that is as minimalistic as possible. That's it.

Comment: Great! I tried to be as clear as possible. Did I not?

Comment: Again: You're the master! Respect!

Comment: I'm not the OP. I wish the OP would update his post and ask a comprehensible question.

Comment: Oops... Indeed, your're not the OP. Still tired. What is the problem with the question?

Comment: datatable is sub of dataset,I can access datatable from one page(Form1) to another page(Form2) for keep into dataset or datatable of Form2?

Comment: I don't understand your question. What do you want to do ?

Comment: I want access datatable from another form.But datatable get value from dataset

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your question as-is as I answered to it as I understsood it. Provide code of what you want to do, please.